# How can I terminate netcat so my script can loop again?

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04, terminate, netcat

I'm running a bash script that goes through the list of my remote server IPs, connects via netcat (telnet) for each line, and runs a few commands.

The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to terminate netcat so the script can loop to the next IP in the list.

Here's the relevant bit:

```
#!/bin/bash
while ISF= read -r line;do
(
sleep 3
printf 'command1'
sleep 3
printf 'command2'
sleep 3
) | nc $line
done < ~/servers.txt
```

The remote servers don't send an EOF, so is there something I can `echo` or `printf` at netcat to terminate netcat so the script can loop through again? I would really rather not do a `-w` flag for a timeout, because I have quite a few servers I need to do this on, and a timeout would make it take much longer.

Comment: Hmmm, just one long guess: `printf 'echo "QUIT"'` ?

Comment: No, that won't work because that just sends the word "QUIT" to the remote server. I would assume that there is some sort of escape function in netcat similar to telnet (CTRL+]) but I don't know what it is.

Comment: But sending the quit command to an active connection would close the current connection... no ? Anyways, `printf 'echo "^Z"'` IIRC.

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the correct way to iterate over a file line-by-line.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, I kinda just threw this together quickly. Code is updated above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify a timeout after which `nc` will exit if it receives no further input, either from the remote end or via standard input.

```
... | nc "$line" -w 10   # Choose a value for -w as appropriate
```

Comment: Thanks, and I think this example might be better with `-w 1` which is the shortest amount of time that -w will accept, it doesn't accept 0 or floating point integers (e.g. .5).

Comment: The focus of the answer is using `-w` at all to allow a timeout. I used 10 in the answer just to match the 9+ seconds the command in the original question would take to execute.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your version of netcat, but `-c` should do what your looking for.  From the usage statement of gnu netcat (which is likely what you're running on Ubuntu):

```
 -c, --close                close connection on EOF from stdin
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that option in my version.

Comment: Do you have a `-w` option to timeout if nothing is received from standard input for some specified period of time?

Comment: @chepner is that how that works? I thought that was a timeout for the process itself, ie., timer starts on connect and disconnects after that length of time regardless of input.

Comment: I think? My man page says 'If a connection and stdin are idle for more than timeout seconds, then the connection is silently closed.' I read that as any activity on standard input or from the remote end is sufficient to reset the timer.

Comment: @chepner You're right. That does work. If you put it as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Comment: In bsd netcat, the equivalent option is `-N`